# Could not get fullduration of my MP3 file

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, flowplayer

I am trying to get fullduration my MP3 file but it returns me NaN,

Here is my code:

```
 <script>

            $f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
                clip: {
                    // our song
                    url: '1.mp3',



                    // when music starts grab song's metadata and display it using content plugin
                    onStart: function(){
                        var fullduration = parseInt(this.getClip().fullDuration, 10);
                        alert(fullduration);
                        var p = this, c = p.getClip(), d;
                        timer = setInterval(function(){
                            d = showtime(c.fullDuration);
                            $("a[href=" + c.url + "] > samp").html(showtime(p.getTime()) + "/" + d);
                        }, 1000);

                    }
                },

                plugins: {

                    // content plugin settings
                    content: {
                        url: 'flowplayer.content-3.2.0.swf',
                        backgroundColor: '#002200',
                        top: 25,
                        right: 25,
                        width: 160,
                        height: 60
                    },

                    // and a bit of controlbar skinning  
                    controls: {
                        backgroundColor: '#002200',
                        height: 30,
                        fullscreen: false,
                        autoHide: false,
                        volume: false,
                        mute: true,
                        time: true,
                        stop: false,
                        play: false

                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I am also getting same error...please help me too

Comment: Did you try `console.log(this.getClip().fullDuration)` and see what it actually is you are trying to parse as an integer?

Comment: @MikeL. It should be a float.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your code using flowplayer version 3.2.7 and 3.2.8. With version 3.2.7 I get the same error and with 3.2.8 I get the duration in seconds which is what is expected. So you'll need to upgrade and change the following from

```
http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf
```

to

```
http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.8.swf
```